# How to customize ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want create this design with `ViewPager`.
[image]

How can I customize `viewpager` and create this?

Comment: Start with the official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html Create the ViewPager, the different pages with an ImageView and some TextViews and add the page indicators. It is very easy

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez, thanks man. can you send me code? please I am amateur and I really need this. please my friend

Comment: I can't sorry, the code involved in this is too much, if you want to learn start from the link I provided if you don't want to learn try in another place, I doubt anybody here will do your task.

Comment: You check this github for the sample https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator the code sample was there in there repo.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Create a `Fragment` and its layout `XML` with `ImageView` and right aligned `TextView's` for  your `Fragment` page.

**2.** Use `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to populate `Fragment's` on `ViewPager`.

**3.** For bottom `Indicator` follow below tutorial.

**Here is a good tutorial:**

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement **Slider** in **android**, app according you **requirement**.
There is an example on [code](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)